# error in posting in wordpress with xmlrpc and vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, wordpress, compiler-errors, xml-rpc

i'm trying to post in wordpress with xmlrpc & vb.net but this error occured
what does it mean?!

[image]

Comment: Please post the error text, not an image of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your project properties so that the Target Frameworkis set to the full .Net Framework 4.0 not just the Client framework 4.0.

This is because an assembly that you are referencing (CookComputing) has a reference to the System.Web assembly which is only available in the Full framework.

[Documentation on how to do this is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)